# How to get current User/ClaimsPrincipal in Middleware .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to access Current User's claims in Middleware before request goes any Controllers.

On login I have set claims like this.

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.ID.ToString());

//...

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var claim = httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
```

It returns *null*.

I know that we can access this using `ControllerBase.User` property in Controllers (*which I am able to get*), But I need to access it in Middleware.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: depends on middleware registration order. Make sure your middleware is registered after the authentication middleware(s)

Comment: @Nkosi You are awesome, Thank you. If you put this as answer, I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you can access this using `ControllerBase.User` property in Controllers is because it happens later in the pipeline well after the `User` has been set.

This depends on middleware registration order.

> The order that middleware components are added in the `Startup.Configure` method defines the order in which the middleware components are invoked on requests and the reverse order for the response. The **order** is critical for security, performance, and functionality.

The `User` is set by the authentication middleware(s) so make sure your custom middleware that depend on having `User` is registered after the authentication middleware(s)

```
//...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
// app.UseSession();

app.AddCustomMiddleware();

//...
```

Reference [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/)